# in order to configure sonarqube i tried to change the value of "vm.max_map_count" but it seems to still be stuck at the default value

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, sonarqube, vps, sonarqube-scan

So i am installing sonarqube 9.9 LTS on a vps (ubuntu 20.4), I did everything from installing postgresql, java 11 and sonarqube, and the sonarqube status is active, the only problem that remains is the elasticSearch configuration.
the vm.max_map_count stays the same even after I change it in the configuration file /etc/sysctl.conf and do "sudo sysctl -p" because i cannot reboot (other applications are hosted on the same server)

Do you have any idea how I can fix this ? without rebooting the server? because i tried this same installation locally and it works

I tried changing the config file to configure the elasticSearch but it woudlnt change.